# After first software update on ubuntu 14.04 pc boots to a black screen

Tags: boot, 14.04, updates, dell, update-manager

I've installed ubuntu 14.04 twice on my OptiPlex 990 Dell computer. Both times, after first software update the pc boots to a black screen. I thought it was a video driver problem, so the second time before the software update I changed from the generic drivers to a proprietary one. I've tried many things to try to recover the linux installation, but nothing seemed to work. I've installed ubuntu 14.04 a third time, but now I haven't installed software updates. What should I do?

My hardware profile can be found [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qepnpibuz3myj79/hardwareprofile.html)

The result from `sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
  andre@andre-OptiPlex-990:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Calculating upgrade... Done
  The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
    kde-l10n-engb
  Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
  The following packages have been kept back:
    libqt5gui5 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
  The following packages will be upgraded:
    account-plugin-aim account-plugin-jabber account-plugin-salut
    account-plugin-yahoo app-install-data apport apport-gtk apt
    apt-transport-https apt-utils bash bsdutils compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome
    compiz-plugins-default cups-browsed cups-filters cups-filters-core-drivers
    dpkg duplicity empathy empathy-common evince evince-common
    evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common
    evolution-data-server-online-accounts firefox firefox-locale-en
    firefox-locale-es flashplugin-installer fontconfig fontconfig-config gdb
    gettext gettext-base ghostscript ghostscript-x gir1.2-ebook-1.2
    gir1.2-ebookcontacts-1.2 gir1.2-edataserver-1.2 gir1.2-freedesktop
    gir1.2-glib-2.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0
    gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0
    gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gnome-calculator gnome-control-center-shared-data
    gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-sudoku gstreamer1.0-alsa
    gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
    gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x hud ifupdown
    im-config indicator-printers initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin
    iputils-arping iputils-ping iputils-tracepath kate-data katepart kde-runtime
    kde-runtime-data kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdoctools
    language-pack-en language-pack-gnome-en libapt-inst1.5 libapt-pkg4.12
    libasprintf-dev libasprintf0c2 libbaloocore4 libbaloofiles4 libbalooxapian4
    libblkid1 libcamel-1.2-45 libcgmanager0 libcompizconfig0 libcupsfilters1
    libdecoration0 libdpkg-perl libebackend-1.2-7 libebook-1.2-14
    libebook-contacts-1.2-0 libecal-1.2-16 libedata-book-1.2-20
    libedata-cal-1.2-23 libedataserver-1.2-18 libegl1-mesa libegl1-mesa-drivers
    libelf1 libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3 libfontconfig1 libfontembed1
    libfreetype6 libgail-3-0 libgail-common libgail18 libgbm1 libgettextpo-dev
    libgettextpo0 libgexiv2-2 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgl1-mesa-dri
    libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libgles2-mesa libgnome-control-center1
    libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls26 libgs9 libgs9-common
    libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
    libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
    libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libgudev-1.0-0
    libhud2 libido3-0.1-0 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjbig0 libjson-c2
    libjson0 libkatepartinterfaces4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4
    libkdeclarative5 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5 libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4
    libkemoticons4 libkfile4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4 libkio5 libkjsapi4
    libkjsembed4 libkmediaplayer4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4 libkntlm4
    libkparts4 libkprintutils4 libkpty4 libkrosscore4 libktexteditor4
    libkxmlrpcclient4 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 libmount1 libnautilus-extension1a
    libnepomuk4 libnepomukcleaner4 libnepomukcore4abi1 libnepomukquery4a
    libnepomukutils4 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libokularcore4 libopenvg1-mesa
    liboxideqt-qmlplugin libpam-systemd libplasma3 libpurple-bin libpurple0
    libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5
    libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5
    libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5 librhythmbox-core8 libsane libsane-common
    libselinux1 libsmbclient libsolid4 libssl1.0.0 libsystemd-daemon0
    libsystemd-journal0 libsystemd-login0 libthreadweaver4 libtiff5 libudev1
    libunity-control-center1 libunity-core-6.0-9 libuuid1 libwayland-egl1-mesa
    libwbclient0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwhoopsie0
    libxatracker2 libxfont1 libxml2 libxml2-utils lightdm linux-firmware
    linux-headers-3.13.0-24 linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic
    linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic
    linux-libc-dev locales ltrace mcp-account-manager-uoa mount nautilus
    nautilus-data nautilus-sendto-empathy nepomuk-core-data nepomuk-core-runtime
    network-manager-gnome okular openssh-client openssl patch
    plasma-scriptengine-javascript python-cupshelpers python-libxml2
    python-pexpect python-samba python3-apport python3-lxml
    python3-problem-report python3-software-properties python3-update-manager
    qtdeclarative5-dialogs-plugin qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin
    qtdeclarative5-privatewidgets-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
    qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin
    qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin-assets
    qtdeclarative5-window-plugin rhythmbox rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-mozilla
    rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune
    rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins rsync samba-common
    samba-common-bin samba-libs sane-utils simple-scan smbclient software-center
    software-properties-common software-properties-gtk ssh-askpass-gnome
    system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-gnome
    system-config-printer-udev systemd-services thunderbird
    thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-gb
    thunderbird-locale-en-us thunderbird-locale-es thunderbird-locale-es-ar
    thunderbird-locale-es-es tzdata ubuntu-drivers-common udev unity
    unity-control-center unity-greeter unity-services unity-settings-daemon
    update-manager update-manager-core usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk
    util-linux uuid-runtime webapp-container webbrowser-app whoopsie
    xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon xul-ext-ubufox
  316 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
  Need to get 256 MB/258 MB of archives.
  After this operation, 19,4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Comment: Type `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` and copy/paste the results of the latter command, please

Comment: I've updated the question. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Did you install ubuntu or kubuntu? Have you installed any additional software since installing the system? What kind of graphics do you have - do you have a dedicated card or is it all handled by the processor (AMD or Intel processor, if handled by processor)?

Comment: I installed ubuntu. I have indeed installed additional software after installing the system. I just received this computer from a colleague, and it appears it has two video graphics cards: a Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series] and a 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller.

Comment: I've talked to my colleague and he says he had the black screen issue on this computer too while using openSuse. However, he told me that it was a graphical problem in that when booting the brightness went down to zero. It could be fixed with the keyboard. Should I risk the update?

Comment: It's certainly worth trying if it's not too difficult to redo the installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I asked this question the version I had installed was 14.04.0 (Trusty). I waited a bit and I can know say that after upgrading this week to 14.04.1 (Trusty Tahr) I have not experienced the same issue again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my laptop and live cd of Ubuntu 14.04.
When you load the live cd, press left <kbd>shift</kbd>. choose your language. press <kbd>F6</kbd>. choose `pci=off`, then  <kbd>Esc</kbd>. then try Ubuntu. you have to try Ubuntu before you install it. then choose install from desktop icon.

Comment: I have no problem installing ubuntu. After installing, everything works just fine. The problem is when I install software updates.